# Comparison operator not recognizing two identical numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a very strange issue, with the following code (removed all irrelevant parts, so the code probably looks like it does nothing):

```
def get_items(cred, items):
    for i in range(0, len(items)):
        for j in range(0, len(items)):
            if items[i] + items[j] == cred:
                result = [i + 1, j + 1]
                result.sort()
                break
            else:
                result = [None, None]
    return result

def main():
    for idx, val in enumerate(content):
        cred = 200
        items = [150, 24, 79, 50, 88, 345, 3]

        output = get_items(cred, items)
```

The problem I am having is with the `if items[i] + items[j] == cred:` line, because it should be true (when i = 0 and j = 3), but it never evaluates to true, depsite the fact that I have tried printing out both `items[i] + items[j]` and `cred` right before the `if` statement, and they both show up as 200. Yet the `get_items` method returns `[None, None]`.

They are both definitely integers, so I am completely lost as to how this is happening?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882

Comment: Did you try putting a `print` statement in the `if` to see if it's evaluating to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the `break` to break both loops. It only breaks the inner loop; the outer loop keeps going, and `result` gets reset to `[None, None]`. Just `return` the result immediately instead of breaking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overriding result on each iteration. try like this:

```
def get_items(cred, items):
   result= []
   for i in range(0, len(items)):
       for j in range(0, len(items)):
           print(items[i] + items[j], cred)
           if (items[i] + items[j]) == cred:
               result.append([i + 1, j + 1])
               #result.sort()
               break
           else:
               result.append( [None, None])
   print(result)

cred = 200
items = [150, 24, 79, 50, 88, 345, 3]

output = get_items(cred, items)
```