# search function only finds first item in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was trying to make a basic search function in python using conditions and for loops like this:

```
emails = ["me@gmail.com", "you@hotmail.com", "them@yahoo.com"]
def search(keyword):
    for i in emails:
        if keyword in i:
            return i
        else:
            return "Item not found"

keyword = input("Enter search term: ")
print (search(keyword))
```

but my function only works when the keyword is part of the first item. for example if I tried searching for 'me' or 'gmail' it would return "me@gmail.com"

```
mac$ python3 for_loop.py
     Enter search term: gmail
     me@gmail.com
```

If I tried searching for 'you', it returns the false (else) statement "Item not found".

```
mac$ python3 for_loop.py
     Enter search term: hot
     Item not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Move the `return "Item not found"` out of the `if/else` construct and place it after the loop.

Comment: When you `return` : that is the end of your function, forever, until it is invoked again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching array reports "not found" even though it's found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found)

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowing the search of the list to finish. Your function checks the first item, and when it doesn't find the keyword in the string, returns `"Item not found"` without bothering to check the rest of the items. Instead try the following:

```
def search(keyword):
    for i in emails:
        if keyword in i:
            return i
    return "Item not found"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I always thought there had to be an ELSE statement after an IF statement.

Comment: @JohnJamesJefferson Nope.  If you ever want to have a line of code that does nothing, you can use the `pass` keyword.