# If/Else statement returns

Tags: c++, linked-list, return

This section of code keeps throwing an error, "not all control paths return a value". I'm not entirely sure how to rewrite this so that I can fix the error. Other than the returns, this is what I need this section of code to do. Should I create a new variable that I declare within the if/else statement and then have the return for that variable right before the ending bracket?

```
node * LList::search(int srchKey)
{
    node * p = head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->key == srchKey)
        {
            return p;
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Think: what if the loop is never entered? Also, I can't see when `p = p->next;` would ever run. That should give dead code warnings.

Comment: `p = p->next;` will never be executed. Either the `if` or `else` block executes, and both of them return from the function, which ends the loop.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it that way, @Carcigenicate.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for pointing that out as well. Our professor included an example in the PowerPoint slides that I was similar to this one. So as long as there is an if/else, the other statement is useless?

Comment: Not in general. Only in this case because both of them return from the function.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for clearing that up and helping me!

Answer (score 3):

If `head` is NULL, `search()` will exit without reaching any `return` statement.  The return value will be indeterminate.  That is what the compiler is complaining about.

If `head` is not NULL, `search()` will check only the first node and then `return` a value, it will not search the whole list.  Because of that, the `return NULL;` statement should not be inside the loop at all. It will exit `search()` as soon as it encounters an element that doesn't match, rather than continuing to the next element in the list.

This is similar to the problem I describe in [Searching array reports "not found" even though it's found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/#42913882).

You should wait until the loop ends before doing `return NULL;`. If you get there, it means the item being searched for really wasn't found.

```
node * LList::search(int srchKey)
{
    node * p = head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->key == srchKey)
        {
            return p;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another return statement after the while loop. One possible code path is that the program never enters the while loop. A simple

```
return NULL;
```

should fix it. 
EDIT: Also, your loop will only ever make one pass through. I would remove the (if p == NULL) block; it is useless. I see your intent, but the way to implement it is how I described above.

Comment: This is a perfect answer addressing his warning, but it could be even better if you added a bit about how he can only ever make one loop iteration!

Comment: Btw, you can suggest an edit if you see something like that. Saves me the trouble of doing it myself! :)

Comment: At my rep if I make an edit it goes through immediately. So especially for something as big as that, in my experience suggesting in a comment usually works out better :)

Answer (score 1):

when `while` condition is `false`, then you do not have `return`.

Add a `return` outside `while` in case you do not enter the loop.

Moreover, `p = p->next;` will never be executed because you exit the loop before reaching it because of `if-else`.

Regarding the logic, It seems to me that you do not need the `else` part at all. try to omit it and place `return NULL` before the end of the routine.