# Python login systsem that only works for one user and not for others

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
username=input("Enter username ")
password=input("Enter password ")

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as username_finder:
    for lines in username_finder:
        if line.startswith('Username: '):
            if line.strip() == "Username: "+username and "Password: "+password:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist")
```

The format in the file looks like this `Username: john password: psw123 '

When I put multiple users in to the file and then try the code it sayes the username and password it correct and incorrect for some reason

Comment: `and "Password: "+password` will always succeed, since the truthiness of a non-empty string is always true.

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: `for lines in username_finder:` should be `for line in username_finder:` without this typo I get expected behavior, can you show how you get both correct and incorrect output? Can you also show an example `Username: Password` line in the `myfile.txt`? The description suggests there are no data labels, but the code suggests there are data labels.

Comment: @bob786 python if statements don't work like english. The line should be `if line.strip() == "Username: "+username and line.strip() == "Password: "+password:`

Comment: @JoyalMathew How can that be right? How can the line be equal to two different strings?

Comment: @Barmar Oh, you're right. I'm not completely sure what bob wanted there because `"Password: "+password` will always be `True`.

Comment: sorry i asked for the wrong thing i meant if the input in the file was this                       username: john password: j123456

Comment: also how would i loop it if they got the username or password wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's analyze a part of your code.

The condition in your command

```
if line.strip() == "Username: "+username and "Password: "+password:
```

is possible to write with parentheses (by the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)) as

```
(line.strip() == ("Username: " + username)) and ("Password: " + password)
```

Now, the right-hand operator of the resulting `and` operation

```
("Password: " + password)
```

is a *nonempty string*, and - consequently - evaluated as `True` (see [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)), which makes your `if` statement the same as

```
if line.strip() == "Username: " + username
```

and, consequently, the password is never checked.

---

Now, to the logic of your program:

In your input file you don't have the words *"Username: "* and `"Password: "`, but something as

```
JohnDoe: pswd123
```

so the string literals `"Username: "` and `"Password: "` are totally inappropriate in your `if` statements. You wanted compare the *entered* username with the username *in your file*, and the *entered* password with the password *in your file*, in our example something like

```
if (username == "JohnDoe") and (password == "pswd123"):
```

or - following the format of lines in your input file -

```
if (username + ": " + password) == "JohnDoe: pswd123":
```

The right-hand part of `==` is simply *the line of your input file*, so your `if` statement may look as

```
if (username + ": " + password) == line:
```

so the (corrected) code of your program becomes

```
username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")

with open("myfile.txt") as username_finder:
    for line in username_finder:
        if (username + ": " + password) == line.strip():
            print("Correct")
            break;            # No need to search other lines   
    else:
        print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist")
```

Note the `else` branch of the `for` loop - it will perform only in the case when the loop is *naturally exhausted*, not interrupted by the `break` statement - see [The for statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for solving this for me and i understand what u are saying and now it makes a lot of more sense

Comment: Also one more question say that the input in the file is this                        
username: JohnDoe password: pswd123                                                                      how would u make the code find the username password this way

Comment: Change the part `if (username + ": " + password)` to `if ("username: " + username + " password: " + password)`. Note the space symbol in "username: " and 2 space symbols in " password: ".

Comment: how would i loop it if they got the username or password wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, but I'll try to answer you anyway. How the program find out that the combination username/password is wrong? Only by exhausting the input file, i. e. the `for` loop. In which situation the `else:` branch will take on its role.

Answer (score 2):

If the file just contains the usernames and passwords, not the words `Username:` and `Password`, you should you should not have those strings in your equality check. It should be:

```
if line.strip() == username + ":" + password:
```

Also, you should not print that the name is not found in the `else` condition. The input will only match one line in the file, you'll print an error message for every other line. You should break out of the loop when you find a match, and print the error message in the `else:` clase of the `for` loop. See [Searching array reports "not found" even though it's found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882)

If you want to keep asking for the password until it's correct put everything in a loop.

```
check_failed = True
while check_failed:
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")

    with open("myfile.txt") as username_finder:
        for line in username_finder:
            if (username + ": " + password) == line.strip():
                print("Correct")
                check_failed = False
                break;
        else:
            print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist")
```

Comment: how would i loop it if they got the username or password wrong?

Comment: Put the code in a `while True:` loop. When they get the password correct, use `break` to get out of the loop.

Comment: could you please actually show me the code with the loop in it

Comment: Seriously? I added it.

Comment: Is it really much different from how you'd do it in languages you're not new to?