# Test whether all array elements are factors of a number - return inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I have the following question:

> Write a function that returns true if all integers in an array are factors of a number, and false otherwise.

I tried the code below:

```js
function checkFactors(factors, num) {

  for (let i=0; i<factors.length; i++){
    let element = factors[i];
      console.log(element)

    if (num % element !== 0){
      return false 
    }
    else {
      return true
    }
  }
}

console.log(checkFactors([1, 2, 3, 8], 12)) //➞ false
```

My solution returns true which is wrong.  I know it's the else statement that's messing it up.  But I want to understand why the else statement can't go there.

Comment: You should get the `return true` out of the loop ;) and leave the `return false` inside the loop :) The reason for it is that otherwise your loop really stops after the first checking, returning either true or false, and you want it to return false as soon as something is not a factor. The return true outside of the loop would then indicate that all numbers supplied where factors of the number argument

Comment: FYI, it's not just you, this is one of the most common errors people make when they first start out with programming and loops. :-)

Comment: @t.j.crowder yet we don't have a good dupetarget for it.

Comment: @JonasWilms - Yeah, I bookmarked this one on the basis that there isn't a lot of extraneous stuff, it really is just the earlier return thing. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882 is the general dupe I wrote for this class of problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Just place return true out of for loop,**

If you keep `return true` in `else part` as soon as any of value which does not satisfies `num % element !== 0` your code will `return true` which should not happen in this case as you're checking for all the values in array should be factor of given number

> Let's understand by 1st example

- On first element in array `1` it will check if condition  `num % element !== 0` which turns out false, so it will go to else condition and `return true` from function and will not check for rest of values.
- So you need to keep `return true` at the end so if any of the value in loop doesn't satisfy the if condition than only control will go to `return true`

```js
function checkFactors(factors, num) {

  for (let i=0; i<factors.length; i++){
    let element = factors[i];
    if (num % element !== 0){
      return false 
    }
  }
  return true
}



console.log(checkFactors([1, 2, 3, 8], 12)) //➞ false
console.log(checkFactors([1, 2], 2))
```

> **In short** - In such case where you want all of them must match a condition as a thumb rule you can consider it like

1. keep the `failing case` return value inside for loop
2. keep the `passing case` return value at the end of function

JS have a inbuilt method [**Array.every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for such cases

```js
function checkFactors(factors, num) {
   return factors.every(element => num % element === 0);
}
console.log(checkFactors([1, 2, 3, 8], 12)); 
console.log(checkFactors([1, 2], 2));
```

Answer (score 7):

You are working in a chocolate store, and your boss tells you to check wether all chocolates (there are *chili chocolate*, *caramel chocolate* and *coffee chocolate*) are delicious. He tells you the following:

*Go through all chocolates, and for each chocolate, taste it, if it is fine,  tell me that everything is fine, otherwise tell me that something is wrong*¹

You start with the first chocolate, which is *chili chocolate*, it tastes delucious, you go to your boss and tell him that everything is fine. Your boss yells at you because you haven't tasted the *caramel chocolate* and the *coffee chocolate* yet.

You realize that your boss actually wanted you to do:

*Go through the chocolates, for each chocolate, taste it, if it doesnt taste well tell, tell me immeadiately, otherwise continue until you tasted them all, then return to me and tell me that everything is fine.*²

Or in code:

```
 // ¹
  function checkChocolates(chocolates) {
    for(const chocolate of chocolates) {
       if(isTasty(chocolate)) {
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
    }
 }

 // ²
 function checkChocolates(chocolates) {
   for(const chocolate of chocolates) {
     if(isTasty(chocolate)) {
       continue; // this could be omitted, as a loop keeps looping nevertheless
     } else {
       return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
 }
```

As this is a very common task in programming, there is already a shorter way to express this:

```
 if(chocolates.every(isTasty)) {
   alert("all chocolates are fine");
 } else {
    alert("Oh, that doesnt taste good");
 }
```

whereas `isTasty` is a function taking a chocolate and returning either true or false.

---

If you didn't grasp it yet, just *try it out!* Buy some chocolate, and taste it! If someone tells you "eating choclate isn't learning", respond with "I'm doing [rubber duck debugging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)" and no one can complain :)

Comment: A tiny quibble - it's "chocolate", not "choclate".

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop the input `num` was was tested for divisibility, if the `num` was divisible the control was going in the `else` block from where the function returned `true`.

The loop was not checking for all numbers of the input array it was returning `true` when the *first number was divisible*.

Just use a flag variable to see if *all of the elements* are divisible by the input number `num`, if any one is not divisible the `flag` will set to `false` and then we can `break` out of the loop and return it as there is no point to check the other numbers.

```js
function checkFactors(factors, num) {
  let flag = true;
  for (let i=0; i<factors.length; i++){
    let element = factors[i];
    if (num % element !== 0){
      flag = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}

console.log(checkFactors([1, 2, 3, 8], 12)); 
console.log(checkFactors([1, 2], 2));
console.log(checkFactors([2, 4, 3, 6, 9], 12));
console.log(checkFactors([3, 5, 2, 6, 9], 15));
console.log(checkFactors([4, 2, 8, 1], 16));
```

You can also use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check the same in a concise way:

```js
function checkFactors(factors, num) {
   return factors.every(element => num % element === 0);
}
console.log(checkFactors([1, 2, 3, 8], 12)); 
console.log(checkFactors([1, 2], 2));
console.log(checkFactors([2, 4, 3, 6, 9], 12));
console.log(checkFactors([3, 5, 2, 6, 9], 15));
console.log(checkFactors([4, 2, 8, 1], 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "else" causing the issue. I removed it and added "return true" outside of for loop.

```
function checkFactors(factors, num) {

  for (let i=0; i<factors.length; i++){
    let element = factors[i];
      console.log(element)

    if (num % element !== 0){
      return false 
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: He is looking for an explanation as well though

Comment: I see Icepickle has explained in the question comments nicely! Jonas Wilms's answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code's logic is wrong. You should check all the array's Elements, if all elements satisfy the condition, return true, but if one of them not satisfy the condition, return false immediately. The else means one item satisfy the condition, but not all elements. That's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkFactors = (factors, num) => factors.reduce((acc, x)=>acc && num%x===0);
```

or

```
const checkFactors = (factors, num) => factors.every(x => num%x===0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            package Map;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Scanner;

            public class Question3 {
                public void factorize(int number) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                        if (number % i == 0) {
                            temp.add(i);
                        }
                    }
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter the number do you want to check factorize: ");
                    int i = sc.nextInt();
                    Question3 question3 = new Question3();
                    question3.factorize(i);

                }
            }
```