# Code does not recognise string from a specific cell from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm creating a login and menu program and I have a CSV file with the login and passwords from some users I have invented. When I run the program, it does without any errors, but when I introduce a right username and password, It doesn't work properly.

My code prints "Access not granted" when it should print "Access granted".

This is how my CSV looks when I print it in the console:

```
[['Username' 'Password' 'Access Level'] ['booker12' '12se74' '1'] ['grey07' '04ap67' '1'] ['johnson81' '30no86' '1'] ['jenkins46' '14ju73' '1'] ['smith79' '09ja61' '1'] ['ccastrej' 'superuser03' '3'] ['ssofia' 'semigod1' '2'] ['isabella' 'payasian' '2'] ['pablitohesk' 'soccer13' '2'] ['teacher' 'igradethis100' '3'] ['pedrocorte' 'asturiano' '1'] ['andrea' 'jesusito' '1']]
```

Here is the code I have right now:

```
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np

def Main():
    login()

def login():
    with open('MatrixAccess.csv') as csvfile: #I import the csv file
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';') #I read through it
        x = list(reader) # I convert the csv into an array to loop through it easier with the numpy library
    print(np.matrix(x)) #I print it to check if I imported it correctly
    print("Username: ")
    str1 = input()
    print("Password: ")
    str2 = input()
    for i in [2]:
            for j in [i]: #I have to convert the ints to lists so I can iterate through the list
                if(str1 == x[i][j] and str2 == x[i][j+1]):
                    print("Access granted")
                else:
                    print("Access not granted")

def menu():
    print("************MAIN MENU**************")
```

Comment: That's not a CSV file. Is everything really on one line like that?

Comment: `for i in [2]` and `for j in [i]` reduces to `i, j = 2, 2` and no need for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are totally wrong. `for i in [2]` just means to loop over that 1-element list, which is no different from just writing `i = 2` without any loop.

You should be looping over the list `x`, which contains the result of reading the file.

```
for row in x[1:]:
    if str1 == row[0] and str2 == row[1]:
        print("Access granted")
        break
else:
    print("Access not granted")
```

`x[1:]` skips over the header line. Notice that the `else:` block is on the `for` loop, not the `if` statement; this runs only if you get to the end of the loop without breaking. If you put it on the `if` statement, it will report an error for every line in the file that doesn't match; see [Searching array reports "not found" even though it's found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882)