# Else stament runs regardless of if statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to look through a long list of json objects in a `for` loop but when my `if` statement is called my `else` statement still runs.

Code

```py
import requests
command = message.content.lower()
command = re.sub("!stock ", "", command)
r = requests.get(api)
response = r.json()

for line in response['data']['stock']:
  if line['country_name'].lower() == command:
  specific = discord.Embed(title="Cloaked Stock Count", description="Stock count for `" + command + "`", timestamp=datetime.now(),
                    color=0xCF22FF, url="https://cloaked.cc/")
  specific.add_field(name=line['country_name'] + " (" + line['iso_code'] + ")", value= "Stock: " + str(line['invite_total']))
  await message.author.send("Stock for `" + command + "`", embed=specific)

  elif line['iso_code'].lower() == command:
  specific = discord.Embed(title="Cloaked Stock Count",
                          description="Stock count for `" + command + "`",
                          timestamp=datetime.now(),
                          color=0xCF22FF, url="https://cloaked.cc/")
  specific.add_field(name=line['country_name'] + " (" + line['iso_code'] + ")",
                    value="Stock: " + str(line['invite_total']))
  await message.author.send("Stock for `" + command + "`", embed=specific)

  else:
  await message.channel.send("Didn't find")
```

API response

```
{
"data":{      "message":"Stock request was successful",
      "exec_time":0.0018777847290039062,
      "stock":[         {
            "iso_code":"DE",
            "country_name":"Germany",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"US",
            "country_name":"United States",
            "invite_total":8
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"GB",
            "country_name":"United Kingdom",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"NO",
            "country_name":"Norway",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"CA",
            "country_name":"Canada",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"AR",
            "country_name":"Argentina",
            "invite_total":3
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"BR",
            "country_name":"Brazil",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"SK",
            "country_name":"Slovakia",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"MX",
            "country_name":"Mexico",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"ID",
            "country_name":"Indonesia",
            "invite_total":2
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"SE",
            "country_name":"Sweden",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"TR",
            "country_name":"Turkey",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"AU",
            "country_name":"Australia",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"EC",
            "country_name":"Ecuador",
            "invite_total":3
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"DK",
            "country_name":"Denmark",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"CH",
            "country_name":"Switzerland",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"CZ",
            "country_name":"Czech Republic",
            "invite_total":0
         
},
         {
            "iso_code":"CL",
            "country_name":"Chile",
            "invite_total":0
         
   }
 }
}
```

When `command` is found in `line['country_name']` my `else` statement still runs and it spams the `await message.channel.send("Didn't find")`

edit:
I tried the same thing with an `elif` chain and I got the same results

Comment: The `else` is not part of that if-statement. It's part of the `if line['iso_code'].lower() == command:` statement.

Comment: I did the same with an elif chain and I got the same results

Comment: Can't tell you a problem with some different code that you haven't posted. Post a [mre].

Comment: Indents are required in python. Without them the code won't run properly

Comment: @khelwood updated it

Comment: The body of the `for` loop isn't indented properly.

Comment: The body of the if statements isn't indented

Comment: The code you've posted shouldn't even run because the indentation is wrong. Please post the actual code.

Comment: I fixed the indentation, it got messed up when posting it

Comment: It's still messed up.

Comment: We can't help until you post with the correct indentation. Use 4 spaces for each indentation level, as recommended in PEP-8.

Comment: Due to the for-loop the if-elif-else part runs multiple times. So the "else" may be executed for some iterations where the previous conditions are false.

Comment: I suspect your problem is what I discuss here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bunch of exclusive `if` statements, instead of playing with `elif`, I'd recommend to use `continue`, if you are sure your `if` statements are fully exclusive, that is, if one runs, the rest is not needed:

```
for line in response['data']['stock']:
    if line['country_name'].lower() == command:
        # your code
        continue

    if line['iso_code'].lower() == command:
        # your code
        continue

    await message.channel.send("Didn't find")
```

Comment: While this might be a good recommendation, I don't see how it would solve his problem. `elif` provides the same exclusion.

Comment: Tried this just now and my `else` statement still runs

Comment: @Barmar this will help with indentation problems