# check through second column by first column id

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 columns under sales table in SQL as below

| id | itemid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 |
| 1 | 32 |
| 1 | 33 |
| 1 | 34 |

I need through the PHP to check by the id, if the $_SESSION['id'] has any item number in the second column then tell the user that the item already exists, otherwise add this item to DB ..
I did do fat the below code but it doesn't work, it will print both conditions if statement

```js
<?php

session_start();
include "connect.php";
$access = isset($_SESSION["userid"]);
if ($access) {
    
    $itemid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "itemid", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    if($itemid !== null && $itemid !== false){
        $SQL = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales where userid = ?");
        if($SQL->execute([$_SESSION["userid"]])){
            if ($SQL->rowCount() > 0){
                while($row = $SQL->fetch()){
                    if((int)$row['itemid'] === $itemid){
                        echo "item is exist";
                    }else{
                        echo "add it to the table";
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reporting "add it to the table" for every row that has a different item ID. You can't know that the item ID isn't found until you get to the end of the loop, if it was never matched. See [Searching array reports "not found" even though it's found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882) for this general problem, which is a common beginner error.

But there's no need for the loop. Check for `itemid` in the SQL query.

```
$SQL = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM sales where userid = ? and itemid = ?");
$SQL->execute([$_SESSION['userid'], $itemid]);
$row = $SQL->fetch();
if ($row['count'] > 0) {
    echo "item is exist";
} else {
    echo "add it to the table";
}
```

Comment: Woooow Amazing Barmar, Thanks a lot, it's working