# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute error when trying to access a variable from a function

Tags: python, function, variables, tweepy, attributeerror

If been working on a twitter bot for a while now, just for fun, but I've been stuck with this single problem. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. Here is the code:

```
def teste():
    tweets = api.home_timeline(2, read_id(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode = 'extended')
    print('Setup is ok!')
    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
        if 'carente' in tweet.full_text.lower():
            print(str(tweet.id) + ' - ' + tweet.full_text)
            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            store_the_id(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)
            teste.x = 1
        elif 'carente' not in tweet.full_text.lower():
            teste.x = 0
        else:
            print('Error no sistema alguem me desconfiguro')

def tweet_timer():
    if time.gmtime().tm_min == '10':
        api.update_status(f'Farid esteve carente {y} vezes')
    else:
        return

while True:
    teste()
    with open('number.txt', 'r') as f:
        read = f.readline
        z = int(read())
    y = z + teste.x
    print(y)
    with open('number.txt', 'w') as f:
        write = f.write(str(y))
        write
    tweet_timer()
    time.sleep(40)
```

I'm trying access the **teste.x** variable out of the function, but when I do at the **y = z + teste.x** it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fredg\Desktop\Programação\Python\Twitter Bot\Website\Word.py", line 69, in <module>
    y = z + teste.x
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: If the `tweets` list is empty, the function never sets `teste.x`, so you'll get that error.

Comment: Setting attributes on a function is not a good practice. Use `return` instead.

Comment: The loop keeps updating `teste.x`, so at the end it just has the value from the last iteration (which is the first tweet because you reversed them). Is that really what you want?

Comment: And the `else:` code can never be executed. Either `carente` is in the text or it's not, there's no other possibility.

Comment: You need to explain what this function is supposed to do? I suspect the logic in the `teste()` function is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882

Answer (score 0):

teste.x is deleted after the function is executed by the garbage collector, you can use a global variable or pass the created outside the function, returning its value from the function for further transfer and use.

Example:

```
def teste(x: int) -> int:
    tweets = api.home_timeline(2, read_id(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode="extended")

    print("Setup is ok!")

    for tweet in reversed(tweets):

        if "carente" in tweet.full_text.lower():
            print(str(tweet.id) + " - " + tweet.full_text)

            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            store_the_id(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)

            x = 1

        elif "carente" not in tweet.full_text.lower():
            x = 0

        else:
            print("Error no sistema alguem me desconfiguro")

    return x


def tweet_timer():
    if time.gmtime().tm_min == "10":
        api.update_status(f"Farid esteve carente {y} vezes")
    else:
        return


x = 0

while True:
    x = teste()

    with open("number.txt", "r") as f:
        read = f.readline
        z = int(read())

    y = z + x

    print(y)

    with open("number.txt", "w") as f:
        write = f.write(str(y))
        write

    tweet_timer()

    time.sleep(40)
```

P.S. I have not tested the functionality of the code due to the lack of the required library, but with the exception of simple possible errors, you will get the result you need

Comment: Why would `teste.x` be garbage collected?

Comment: I used google translate, maybe it translated incorrectly

The garbage collector itself removes the ```teste.x``` after executing the test function teste()

Comment: oh, sorry. I was wrong about the garbage collector, in fact, the problem is that  ```x``` attribute is not always assigned to the function. This code is still working

Answer (score 0):

`teste` is a function ***not*** a class. If you want to have attributes on `teste`, make it a class like this:

```
class teste:
    def __init__():
        tweets = api.home_timeline(2, read_id(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode = 'extended')
        # ...
```

Call it like this:

```
teste_instance = teste()
```

Access `teste_instance.x` inside of `teste` by referencing `self.x`.

Comment: Functions are objects, you can add attributes to any object.

Comment: @Barmar true, but it's not very Pythonic. Classes are much more Pythonic.