# I wrote an if condition in blade file and it's not working

Tags: php, laravel-8

Here is my blade file foreach loop works perfectly but when i want to check the value exist or not then it always show not

```
@foreach ($value as $names)
<h3>{{$names}}</h3>
@endforeach

@if($names =="abc")
<h2>Found</h2>
@else
<h3>Not</h3>
@endif
```

and here is my controller

```
public function load_name()
    {
       
         $values = ['abc','xyz','yyy'];
         return view('name',['value' => $values]);
        
    }
```

and route

```
 Route::get("names",[UserController::class,'load_name']);
```

Comment: Because the `@if` block should be placed inside the `@foreach` loop. Currently it is outside

Comment: Note that you can't tell if `abc` was not found until the end of the loop. Set a variable when the name matches, then check the variable at the end. Otherwise you'll print `Not` for every name that isn't `abc`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913798/searching-array-reports-not-found-even-though-its-found/42913882#42913882

Comment: It checks for every element. but is there any way to print the end of the loop for a particular single value is it exist in the array or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($value as $names)
  <h3>{{$names}}</h3>
  @if($names =="abc")
  <h2>Found</h2>
  @else
  <h3>Not</h3>
  @endif    
@endforeach
```

Comment: It checks for every element. but is there any way to print the end of the loop for a particular single value is it exist in the array or not?